# ActiveModel::Serializer - How can I catch and handle errors for individual resources during collection serialization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

In a rails application, I have a collection I'd like to render as json.  Some of the items in the collection may not successfully serialize due to errors being raised.  I'd like to catch those errors and handle them by reporting them to our error logging service, and also provide a dummy record in the json array to represent the unloadable record so that the client software may use it.

Example desired collection of hashes with 1 unloadable record:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: "foo", ... many other properties },
  { id: 2, name: "bar", ... many other properties },
  { unloadable_record: true, id: 3, name: "baz" }
]
```

I am currently able to achieve this by handling everything in the controller (which is more than I'd like):

```
def index
  render json: safely_serialized_records
end

private

def safely_serialized_records
  @records.map do |r|
    begin
      ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(r, include: "**").as_json
    rescue StandardError => e
      report_unloadable_record(e, r)
      {
        unloadable_record: true,
        id: r.id,
        name: r.name
      }
    end
  end
end
```

But there are downsides to this approach that I'd like to avoid: it puts too much of the view-rendering concern into the controller, the Rails logs no longer attribute the json serialization to the `view` portion of the response time (making the performance less straightforward to assess), and has that "I'm doing it wrong" feeling.

I tried a few other approaches that had to do with setting the `serializer`, `each_serializer`, and `adapter` options on the `render` call.  I implemented custom classes to inherit from sensible bases (e.g. `ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes`) and override `serializable_hash` with something like:

```
def serializable_hash(*args)
  begin
    super
  rescue StandardError => e
    handle_unloadable_record(e, serializer.object)
  end
end
```

... but to no avail.

Is there a clean approach with AMS to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: What sort of errors are you encountering that you need a global rescue like this? That is my first concern, and for me what makes a solution like this feel "dirty". Rather than handling the errors at the level they are happening, you are globally catching them all. It may be required, but likely not. Better to handle those errors at the source.

Comment: @steel This is code that helps run a Foo factory.  I'm rendering a collection of Foo objects.  Each Foo has many relations, and it's attributes for serialization include calls to a long methods.  99% of the Foo objects serialize just fine.  The 1% that won't serialize (for myriad possible reasons) will result in an error when you try to serialize via something like `render json: @foos`, and prevent the entire collection from loading - which disrupts production at the physical Foo factory, resulting in a sadder Foo business. (cont)

Comment: @steel The handling that works for the Foo business is to report the issue to the engineers, and also to the end user with a simple message so that they are at least informed.  I understand where you're coming from, but the Foo factory is very sensitive to disruptions, so rather than let one bad Foo ruin the whole bunch, we're writing software that will report the bad Foos for fixing but let everyone work on the good Foos in the meantime.